# Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl.php on line 87

Tags: php, magento, wamp

I want to access to magento admin in my local wamp , but i get this erreur ,

Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_setopt() in C:\wamp\www\magento\includes\src\Varien_Http_Adapter_Curl.php on line 87

i have installed the extension  php_curl but no result  so have you an idea about the issus of this probleme  ?

Comment: Is your extension enabled ?

Comment: What version of WampServer are you running

Comment: `php_curl` might have not been enabled.

Comment: php_curl is enabled , the version of wampserver is WampServer Version 2.2

Comment: i have verified my php.ini the extension of php_curl is not loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved this with deleting the wampserver and install it again , so thanks my freind for you sugestions

Answer (score 1):

Using the wampmanager menus do this to activate the php_curl extension

```
wampmanager -> PHP -> PHP Extensions -> click the php_curl item in the menus if it is not ticked already.
```

You also need to make sure that these 2 dll's are in the `\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin` folder.

```
ssleay32.dll
libeay32.dll
```

If you are using WAMPServer 2.5 this should be done when you click the extension link on the menu, a SYMLINK will be created for these 2 dll's from the PHP folder where they live.

If you are using pre WampServer 2.5 you will have to copy them from `wamp\bin\php\phpx.y.z` to the `\wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin` folder.

Comment: ssleay32.dll , libeay32.dll  exists already in wamp\bin\apache\apachex.y.z\bin and php_curl is enabled , but always no result realy i don't know why it gives me the issus ,

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly the same error on my development machine. And enabling curl did not resolve the problem although I had both `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll` in my `apache\bin` folder.

The solution was copying also the `libssh2.dll` file to the `apache\bin` folder.

See http://php.net/manual/en/curl.installation.php for reference.